# Why would an algebraic type be only an initial algebra (or vice versa)?

Tags: haskell, recursion, abstract-data-type

In the `recursion-schemes` package we can express the fact that a (strictly-positive) algebraic data type

1. has a signature functor, `f`
2. is the initial `f`-algebra, and
3. is the final `f`-coalgebra

For instance, we can do so for `[a]` with the following code

```
-- (1) define and declare the signature functor, here called Base

data instance Prim [a] x = Nil | Cons a x deriving Functor
type instance Base [a] = Prim [a]

-- (2) demonstrate the initial algebra
instance Foldable [a] where
  project []     = Nil
  project (a:as) = Cons a as

-- (3) demonstrate the final coalgebra
instance Unfoldable [a] where
  embed Nil         = []
  embed (Cons a as) = a:as
```

Notably, for any type where we have (1), (2), and (3) we ought to have that `(project, embed)` witnesses an isomorphism.

It's my understanding that data types at large (or at least strictly-positive ones) are always final/initial co/algebras of some signature functor—in fact, they are always *both*.

So my question is: why have `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` as separate classes? When would a data type be just one or the other?

Currently I can imagine this might be valuable for abstract data types which only want to provide either a folding or unfolding interface, but are there other times as well?

Comment: Do we necessarily have to define reciprocal algebra and coalgebra for any types? Could it be possible that for some type, one would wish to define an algebra constructing the values, and a coalgebra to process them (and not just deconstruct them 'dually')?

Comment: You could definitely, this would mean that your unfolds unfold into a subset of possible values and the folds "view" a subset of the possible data—this almost certainly would occur in an abstract data type (else why abstract it at all?). My read on the intended meanings of `Foldable`/`Unfoldable` is that the `Base` functor should be exactly the signature functor of the type and thus they are reciprocal.

Comment: It seems to me that `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` are for exhibiting the datatypes as algebras and coalgebras respectively, not necessarily initial or final.  (This is probably what @didierc was saying too.)

Comment: @TomEllis You could definitely do that, but do to global uniqueness of instances it feels weird (unless your type is abstract and masquerading as something purely inductive or coinductive, maybe?). For any non-abstract type, there's one best/canonical algebra and one best/canonical coalgebra and they share functors and are inverses.

Answer (score 5):

This might not be an answer to your question, but it is not really true that strictly positive Haskell data types are initial algebras.  The reason for this is that even in the total subset of Haskell (which is what we want to work in when reasoning!) you have infinite data.

For example, the fold of an infinite list is partial.

Comment: I don't keep that tension live in my mind, but you're right. I'm not sure how best to phrase it, though (and I would happily edit the question with any suggestions). I'd like to suggest the idea that the least fixed point and the greatest fixed point coincide in Haskell, or at least that it doesn't restrict you from passing a generator to a fold. That breaks universality, but I don't know how else to say it.